# Knit function that returns dot (graphviz) code as string

Tags: r, graphviz, knitr, dot

Using pure dot inside a knitr chunk with engine = "dot" is straightforward, but you have to write the dot code yourself.

```
<<r dot-ex,  engine = "dot",  echo=FALSE>>=
digraph test123 { 
          A -> B
}
@
```

I want a function to do it for me.

```
dotFun <- function() {
  dotCode <- 'digraph test123 { 
          A -> B
          }'
  return(dotCode)
}
```

and then call this inside a knit chunk similar to a function that returns LaTeX code and knit with result = 'as.is'

```
<<r dot-ex,  engine = "dot">>=
cat(dotFun())
@
```

but this results in :Error in (knit_engines$get(options$engine))(options):
setting chunk option results = 'asis' yields the same error message.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with the current version of knitr (v1.5), but will be possible in the next version (v1.6), which has not been released yet. If you use the [development version on Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr), you can actually assign the source code to a code chunk via the `code` option, e.g.

```
<<dot-ex,  engine = "dot", code = dotFun()>>=
@
```

More on this in the [news for v1.6](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md).

Comment: That's great news Yihui. Thanks alot for your awesome work with Knitr.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason this has to be evaluated within a knitr chunk with that engine? Why not do it directly from R with some system calls? You can write the command to a file, and use `system` to call `dot` on that file, and read the results back into R.

This is, in fact, what `knitr` does. You can probably pretty easily take the `knitr` `dot` engine and wrap it into a function of your own -- see 
https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/engine.R#L144.

Comment: I am using this approach to create tables and lists within r functions and then outputting them by results = "as.is". This feels like the simplest approach. I tried follow Yihui's source code but my r-coding skills seems to be lacking. Do you know of any other example doing this? I.e. run external command and get the generated pdf to be inserted as a figure in LaTeX code for further knitting.